# A very complicated multiple lines problem in the align environment

Tags: align

I have a very complicated multiple lines problem in the align environment to solve.

See the code below and the pdf file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1kX_CbBVoMteHU2MmFlZWJNWDg/edit?pli=1 .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&c_{1}J_{h}>0\text{, }c_{1}J_{h+1}>0\text{, }c_{1}\left( J_{h}+p_{1}\left(
h\right) \right) >0\text{,}\\
&c_{1}\left( \left( J_{h}+J_{h+1}\right) \prod_{v\in \left\{ -1,1\right\} \
}\left( J_{h+v}+p_{1}\left( h\right) \right) -J_{h}J_{h+1}\left(
J_{h+1}-J_{h-1}\right) \right) <0\text{.}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& c_{1}J_{h}>0\text{, }c_{1}J_{h+1}>0\text{, }c_{1}\left( J_{h}+p_{1}\left(
h\right) \right) >0\text{,} & & \\
& c_{1}\Bigg(\left( J_{h}+J_{h+1}\right) \prod_{v\in \left\{ -1,1\right\} \
}\left( J_{h+v}+p_{1}\left( h\right) \right)  & & -  \notag \\
& & & J_{h}J_{h+1}\left( J_{h+1}-J_{h-1}\right) \Bigg)<0\text{.}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

As you see in the pdf file, formulas (1) and (2) are usual situation in the align environment. But if (2) is too long, then we have to divide it into two lines ( something like (4) ).

I think my code is not a good solution for this situation. Because my expected solution should be as follows:

**(i)** Use amsmath package only.

**(ii)** We can not use additional environments except for align, gather, flalign, multline, alignat and split.

**(iii)** Make the spacing of the two lines of (4) be smaller than the spacing of (3) and the first line of (4).

**(iv)** Can not use phantom command.

**(v)** Keep the corresponding brackets in (2) and (4) the same size.

Obviously, my code can not satisfy **(iii)** and **(v)**, so I hope someone can help me. Thanks! Wait for your solutions...

Comment: for (iii) you can always use `\\[value]` with value positive or negative at end of lines. It will add value to regular distance between lines. About (v) it looks like brackets have same size in (2) and (4). In any case, what would you like to get?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `multlined` from `mathtools`. However, my advice is to use `gather` rather than `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
c_{1}J_{h}>0,\quad c_{1}J_{h+1}>0,\quad c_{1}(J_{h}+p_{1}(h))>0, \\
c_{1}\biggl( (J_{h}+J_{h+1}) \prod_{v\in \{-1,1\}}(J_{h+v}+p_{1}(h))-
  J_{h}J_{h+1}(J_{h+1}-J_{h-1})\biggr)<0.
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
&c_{1}J_{h}>0,\quad c_{1}J_{h+1}>0,\quad c_{1}(J_{h}+p_{1}(h))>0, \\
&c_{1}\biggl( (J_{h}+J_{h+1}) \prod_{v\in \{-1,1\}}(J_{h+v}+p_{1}(h))-
  J_{h}J_{h+1}(J_{h+1}-J_{h-1})\biggr)<0.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&c_{1}J_{h}>0,\quad c_{1}J_{h+1}>0,\quad c_{1}(J_{h}+p_{1}(h))>0, \\
&\!\begin{multlined}
  c_{1}\biggl( (J_{h}+J_{h+1}) \prod_{v\in \{-1,1\}}(J_{h+v}+p_{1}(h))-{}\\
    J_{h}J_{h+1}(J_{h+1}-J_{h-1})\biggr)<0.
  \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't use `\left` and `\right` in front of all parentheses. In particular, watch out for `\left` and `\right` when the parentheses are around a big operator such as `\sum` or `\prod`: they'll produce too big delimiters, while `\bigg` usually gives the correct size.

Instead of `\text{, }`, I suggest `,\quad` that gives more room. There's non need to say `\text{,}` or `\text{.}` for the final punctuation.

[image]

If you really can't use `mathtools`, then you can go with `aligned`, manually finding out the alignment points, something like

```
\begin{align}
&c_{1}J_{h}>0,\quad c_{1}J_{h+1}>0,\quad c_{1}(J_{h}+p_{1}(h))>0, \\
&\!\begin{aligned}
  c_{1}\biggl((J_{h}+J_{h+1})& \prod_{v\in \{-1,1\}}(J_{h+v}+p_{1}(h))-{}\\
    &J_{h}J_{h+1}(J_{h+1}-J_{h-1})\biggr)<0.
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

[image]